# Replacing a character in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am having an object with `userGuid` as property. The `userGuid` property has `Guid` value enclosed in double quotes.

I have used `replace()` method, but it is replacing first occurrence of a character only.
Therefore, I have used `replace()` method twice to remove both quotations, like below:

```
var UserID = criteria.userGuid.replace('"', '').replace('"', '');
```

Can anyone suggest the best way to replace single character in a variable?

Comment: As this question was closed as duplicate, I really don't care here, but for future reference it is SO etiquette to accept the *earliest* answer when several identical solutions are provided around the same time. Cheers

Comment: Ok, next time, I will type "give meeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee 5 secs", and will be still the first even if I edit my answer with really useful information in half an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a regex in the `replace` function with `g` modifier:

```
var UserID = criteria.userGuid.replace(/"/g, '');
```

```js
var userGuid = "122343\"EE43\"45\"FG";
var UserID = userGuid.replace(/"/g, '');
document.write(UserID);
```

From [`replace()` reference at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> To perform a global search and replace, either include the `g` switch in the regular expression or if the first parameter is a string, include `g` in the flags parameter.

Comment: You are determined to get this one (even though you came in 6 seconds later) :)

Comment: I did not see your answer in my browser. Also, you made a typo in your answer at the very beginning. And did not provide code itself. Then you added the line I already had in my answer. No. Either sportsmanship, or a duplicate.

Comment: Just to clarify, I stated the correct answer quite clearly in English (minus a single character typo) before you posted *and* there is only one possible way to code that description. If it was not for the fact that you were *only* 6 seconds later than me, it would look like *you copied me*.  :P

Answer (score 2):

Use replace with a RegEx literal instead and the "g" global option

e.g.

```
var UserID = criteria.userGuid.replace(/"/g, '');
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp

Comment: Well done for getting in first.